# Partial differentiation chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

I don't understand why d(phi)/d(x_i) is not d(phi)/d(x_i + st_i) since if I have 
f(s) = g(x,y,z), then the partial derivative of f would be df/ds = dg/dx*dx/ds + dg/dy*dy/ds + dg/dz*dz/ds using the chain rule, and this is the same as in the image but with 
x = x_1 + st_1, y = x_2 + st_2, z = x_3 + st_3.

Answer (score 2):

I do not fully agree with notation; I would rather write $f(s):=\Phi(y(s))$, where
$y(s):=x+st$. I suppose $x$ and $t$ to be fixed. Then, by the chain rule

$$\frac{df}{ds}=\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y_i}\frac{dy_i}{ds}= \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial y_i}t_i,$$

as wished.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I believe your intuition is correct, and this is simply a matter of semantics/unclear notation.

You are taking derivatives of $\phi$ with respect to its argument.

A more clear representation would be $\dfrac{\partial \phi(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_i}$.

Comment: I was trying to add to my initial remark, but timed-out.  It seems as if $ \ x_i \ $ is being used _both_ to denote the components of the function $ \ \Phi \ $ _and_ the components of the position vector $ \ \vec{x} \ . $  The chain-rule is applied sensibly, but the result is not written particularly well...

Comment: I agree, I think the solution by Avitus puts it more clearly.

Comment: It's certainly not the first time I've seen an author do something careless like this...